# Fields of positive characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be an infinite field of characteristic $p>0$. It is true that every element  of $\mathbb F$ is algebaric over the prime subfield $\mathbb F_p$ of $p$ elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider ${\mathbb F}_p (x)$, the field of rational functions over ${\mathbb F}_p$. Is $x$ algebraic over ${\mathbb F}_p$ ?

Comment: Touché ${}{}{}{}$